# Moving from one platform to GC and file conversion

Tags: compatibility, data-conversion, platform

We are moving from an educational platform, headrushapp.com to Google Classroom.  We have about 1000 individual modules that we would like to just upload into GC instead of rewriting ALL of them.  We can download the modules, but converting the format to something that GC can use is where we are stumped.  When you export a module, it is listed as a binary file.  However, when I use a binary convertor, it turns out the file isn't actually binary.  This is WAY above my skill level.  If I could send the file to someone, maybe that will help? We would rather not have to copy/paste that many modules into GC units.  Thanks!

I am very inexperienced with this level of file conversion and programming/coding.  I exported one file as a sample to see if I could convert it to something compatible with Google Classroom (GC), but I was unsuccessful. The file is listed as binary, but using an online file converter has proved ineffective as the system says the file is not binary.  With my inexperience, I don't know what else to try/do.  Does anyone have a way to help?

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mcve] before anybody will be able to provide much help.

Comment: I don't know how to upload a file so I will just link to it in my Google Drive. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C54LtCInE9SlbeI7wQr7erXHRdfqBB8s/view?usp=sharing) @StephenNewell  I hope I did that right.